# Cross launch between 2 different version of Mac OS

Tags: macos

I have two different versions of OS-X installed (via separate partitions)
I now have 2 application folders.
If I run my applications normally (say, from the dock) I am fairly confident that everything will work normally.

Of course an idea that comes to mind is that, it would be convenient to not have to install all applications on both systems.

Anybody tried this? Is it likely that running an app installed on system A from system B will cause errors of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

On Macs, most applications (but not all) will just run.  You can move them by simply dragging/dropping them.  No reinstallation necessary.  If you install it on system A, there is a good chance that it will run fine on system B just by double-clicking its icon.  This is one of the great advantages Macs have over Windows.  You can even move the entire operating system this way.  There is no "registry" like in Windows.  Most programs are entirely self-contained.

Where you might run into trouble is with applications that require product activation (like Adobe products), applications that install kernel extensions (like Parallels or VirtualBox), and Mac OS's built-in apps.  You'd have to reinstall those in each OS instance.

Comment: Holy cow. When one of these days I have to "move the entire OS this way". You tried this?
I'll wait a bit to approve this answer, in case somebody else make useful suggestions.

Comment: Wes is correct here; most Mac apps are self-contained and can run from pretty much anywhere -- another volume's Applications folder, your Desktop, a flash drive, a disk image, whatever. But note that your app preferences (& some kinds of data) are tied to your user account, not the app, so they'll be different depending on which OS you're using.